# Find second lowest non-zero value in R

Tags: r, min

I've just started to learn **R** and I need some help.

I would like to find the lowest non-zero number in certain columns, but if the lowest number is zero then I would like to have the second lowest number.

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
aggregate(M3klar2[,32:35],M3klar2["ID"], function(x) if(min(x)>0) min(x) else if(min(x==0) ??second lowest?? )
```

What should I write after `if(min(x==0))?` Or any other suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please go through the tour and faq in the help section. Please put your code in 'code section'. Also, what is the current result of the code and what have you tried.

Comment: A slightly hacky approach would be `min(x[!!x])`

Answer (score 6):

You don't need an `if` statement.

```
x <- c(0,0,2,3,4,5,6)
> min(x[x > 0])
[1] 2
```

To apply to specific columns (as suggested by @Stephen Henderson)

```
apply(df[,my.choice],2, min(x[x > 0]))
```

Alternatively, If you also have negative numbers, you can replace `x>0` with `x!=0` (Clarification given by @docendo discimus)

Comment: ..so I think he wants to apply that to certain columns `apply(df[,my.choice],2, min(x[x>0]))`

Comment: Yes exactly on certain columns AND also for each individual by "ID". Because the same individual appears on more than one row.

Comment: The lowest non-zero number is not necessarily equal to the lowest _positive_ number (i.e. I would suggest using `min(x[x!=0])`) instead

Comment: @StephenHenderson Indeed. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Rethink it. If a value is less than 0, then you don't need any constraints for 0 values

Comment: But you don't know in advance whether there are negative values. (At least it's not clear from the question)

Comment: In his question, the OP says: "I would like to find the lowest non-zero number". This implies that the values are positive...at least in my mind

Comment: No it doesn't. You are confusing "non-zero" with "non-negative". Perhaps it's just incorrect wording by OP but non-zero doesn't imply positivity.

Comment: You are correct. I think the "Lowest" non-zero was the confusing part.

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c(0,0,2,3,4,5,6)
min(setdiff(x,0))
# [1] 2
```

Will select the lowest value in a vector AFTER 0.

Comment: It didn't work :( Do you mean I should write that after if(min(x==0))?

Comment: I've got a lot of warnings saying: In min(setdiff(x, 0)) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Comment: @Cham, tht probably occurs because there are no other values than 0s in that vector (for that ID). It is the same as running `min(numeric(0))`